# optimizing query having max function

Tags: sql, performance, hibernate, optimization

I want to select a row from table with some conditions and maximum value of some parameter **x**(which is string).I'm currently doing :

```
SELECT FROM myTable mm
WHERE       mm.userId = :userId
  AND       x = (
              SELECT MAX(x)
              FROM   myTable m
              WHERE  m.userId = :userId
                AND  (m.to = :contactNumber OR m.from = :contactNumber)
                AND       ...
            )
```

I'm not sure how optimally 'll inno db execute this query but need help with improving this query. I'm using hibernate.

Comment: So X is a hardwired string and not a column from mm?  that doesn't make sense to me.  If you joined the tables, you could using the having clause (if supported) to compare on your max value

Comment: x is also a column of myTable (mm and m are just aliases)

Answer (score 1):

```
    SELECT TOP 1 * FROM myTable m
      WHERE m.userId = :userId
      AND  (m.to = :contactNumber OR m.from = :contactNumber)
      AND       ...
      ORDER BY m.x DESC
```

Comment: check out my comment on Eric Petroelje post, not sure whether this will give good performance on large data set since filesort will be involved

Answer (score 0):

Similar to C.Zonnenberg's answer, but for MySQL:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable
WHERE userId = :userId
AND  (m.to = :contactNumber OR m.from = :contactNumber)
...
ORDER BY x DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: An **explain** on this statement says **using filesort** and also it runs slower than my query above (though difference is fractional as i don't have much data right now). Also note that i've indexed (userId, to, from) in this  order

Comment: @kcr - what are you ordering by, and do you have an index on that field?

Comment: I just need the row with particular 'userId' and contains the max value of x among the rows with condition  (userId = 'userId' AND (m.to = :contactNumber OR m.from = :contactNumber) AND some more conditions here(none of which involves x)). I have indexed (userId, from) but i guess in this case only userId index can be used

Comment: @kcr - it may be able to use the index by userId and from, but the ORDER BY will require a sort.  So if there isn't an index on `x`, a filesort will be needed.

Comment: my point is we just need the row with max value of x and some other constraints, which can be found in O(n) without sorting, so why use O(nlgn) filesort

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT mm.*
FROM myTable mm
  LEFT JOIN myTable m
    ON mm.UserId = m.UserId
   AND (m.to = :contactNumber OR m.from = :contactNumber)
   AND mm.x < m.x
WHERE mm.userId = :userId
  AND (mm.to = :contactNumber OR mm.from = :contactNumber)
  AND m.userId IS NULL
```

This uses a known technique for finding maximum or minimum values using a LEFT JOIN to self. Basically the technique is like this:

```
 SELECT a.*
 FROM a
   LEFT JOIN a AS a2 ON a.key = a2.key AND a.value < a2.value
 WHERE a2.key IS NULL
```

This returns all the rows from `a` with the maximum values of `value` for every `key`. For minimums you'd basically replace `<` with `>`.